Executing procedure in SSIS Visual Studio with result sets
I am running one of the scripts which uses procedure to fetch some columns. Data keeps changing sometimes there are Location_code column values 1, 2 and 3, sometimes 4.



emp_id
Home_location
Location_1
Location_2
Location_3
Location_4




Cell 1
Cell 2






Cell 3
Cell 4







Based on the positions, if a employee has two positions, Location_3 and Location_4 will be blank. If someone has 4 positions for that emp_id, it would go up to 4 columns for others null. It changes as it uses MaxTally function parameter. N*N and partitions @CRLF and Row number.
Coming back to the main thing when I run this script in SQL command ole db. Source editor as:
EXEC ('exec Procedure name;')
WITH RESULT SETS
    ((EMP_ID VARCHAR (20),
      HOME_LOCATION VARCHAR (20),
      location_1 VARCHAR (10),
      location_2 VARCHAR (10),
      location_3 VARCHAR (10),
      location_4 VARCHAR (10)
    ));

The problem is sometimes location column is only until location_3 no location_4 column, in that case I get error.
I removed Location code 4 parsed the query, and it was good.
I am expecting if there is a way like Count +1 here in Ole Db Source editor to determine automatically, so I don't need to add or remove parameter to solve error.

Your sample data is malformed, it has 6 headers, but only 2 columns in the dataset; where is the data for the other 4 columns?

Also you don't ask anything; what is your question here?

Hi data exists in all the 6 columns but for locations it depends on could be null or number too. The problem is if there is no single employee having 4 positions then only location code 3 columns would be left, I have to remove location code 4 parameter in ssrs editor. is there any way parameter can be used as loop to determine automatically?

Do you mean you return dynamic number of columns? Better just return same number and fill out with nulls?

@siggemannen It is returning other nulls which is good in SQL. currently 6 columns could go be 5 or 7 too, it keeps changing based on employee position. every time I have to remove or add parameter location code 4 or 5 or 6 (add or remove) depends on situation in SSRS Editor as shown above in the last.

If the procedure returns varying amounts of columns, and if it can not be altered, and if no input can direct it's behaviour, then only a trial-and-error approach may work, I believe. It seems a loop with try and catch could get You there.

If the procedure returns varying amounts of columns, and if it can not be altered, and if no input can direct it's behaviour, then only a trial-and-error approach may work, I believe. It seems a sequence of queries within try-and-catch-blocks could get you there. I assume you work in an environment where you can execute code like the following.
DECLARE @success_f BIT = 0
DECLARE @r TABLE(story NVARCHAR(4000))

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t
CREATE TABLE #t(
  EMP_ID VARCHAR (20),
  HOME_LOCATION VARCHAR (20),
  lOCtion_1 VARCHAR (10),
  location_2 VARCHAR (10),
  location_3 VARCHAR (10),
  location_4 VARCHAR (10),
  location_5 VARCHAR (10)
)


IF @success_f = 0
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN  
  INSERT INTO #t(
    EMP_ID
    ,HOME_LOCATION
    ,lOCtion_1
    ,location_2
    ,location_3
    )
  EXEC ('EXEC Procedure name;')  
  SET @success_f = 1
  insert into @r select 'first succeeded'
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
  insert into @r select 'first failed'
END CATCH
else insert into @r select 'first not even tried'


IF @success_f = 0
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN  
  INSERT INTO #t(
    EMP_ID
    ,HOME_LOCATION
    ,lOCtion_1
    ,location_2
    ,location_3
    ,location_4
    )
  EXEC ('EXEC Procedure name;')  
  SET @success_f = 1
  insert into @r select 'second succeeded'
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
  insert into @r select 'second failed'
END CATCH
else insert into @r select 'second not even tried'


IF @success_f = 0
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN  
  INSERT INTO #t(
    EMP_ID
    ,HOME_LOCATION
    ,lOCtion_1
    ,location_2
    ,location_3
    ,location_4
    ,location_5
    )
  EXEC ('EXEC Procedure name;')  
  SET @success_f = 1
  insert into @r select 'third succeeded'
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN
  insert into @r select 'third failed'
END CATCH
else insert into @r select 'third not even tried'


SELECT "@success_f after" = IIF( @success_f = 1
                                 ,'procedure run without error'
                                 ,'procedure NOT run without error' )

SELECT story FROM @r

SELECT 
  EMP_ID
  ,HOME_LOCATION
  ,lOCtion_1
  ,location_2
  ,location_3
  ,location_4
  ,location_5
FROM #t

There are three IF-blocks, each trying a specific number of columns. The first one tries up to location_3, the second up to location_4, the third up to location_5. If there a are other sets of columns that may be returned you need to create an IF-block for them. This code will try each one and if one of them succeeds it will load the data into temp table #t. It also collects some info on what happend.
At the end it returns all columns of #t with the final select, leaving unused columns filled with NULL.
